# Add horizontal line to ggplot() for specified interval of x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add horizontal lines to an existing plot, but I would only like to plot the line for certain intervals of the x-axis.

For example I would like to have a horizontal line at X=1:5 and y=50.

I would use `existing_plot+geom_hline(yintercept = 50)`

Is it also possible to specify the x values somehow?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment()` to add line segment with your own defined starting and ending points (not only horizontal/vertical lines).

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,qsec))+geom_point()+
  geom_segment(aes(x=15,xend=20,y=18,yend=18))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `geom_line`:

```
qplot(x=x,y=y,data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=100:1)) +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:5,y=50))
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found the original data that I'm plotting is stored in a melted variable

Comment: You should this example with the right **aesthetics** Not to use it as it is. Better to read some ggplot2 tutorials and understand how it maps data variables to plot parameters.

Comment: the aesthetics should be right, the original plot is with x=1:10, y=0:1, I used existing_plot+geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:5,y=0.6)), am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Didzis Elferts's method worked out, but thank you very much for your help