# plot iteratively segments over intervals using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame "df" (showing 15 of the 1000 tuples)

```
        inf       sup     frec     prob
     1  1.000318  1.005308   12    0.060
     2  1.005308  1.010297    5    0.025
     3  1.010297  1.015286    5    0.025
     4  1.015286  1.020276    2    0.010
     5  1.020276  1.025265    3    0.015
     6  1.025265  1.030254    3    0.015
     7  1.030254  1.035244    8    0.040
     8  1.035244  1.040233    2    0.010
     9  1.040233  1.045223    3    0.015
     10 1.045223  1.050212    0    0.000
     11 1.050212  1.055201    4    0.020
     12 1.055201  1.060191    1    0.005
     13 1.060191  1.065180    1    0.005
     14 1.065180  1.070169    0    0.000
     15 1.070169  1.075159    1    0.005
```

And i want to plot a segment in the interval of x = [ inf[ i ]:sup[ i ] ], and in the y axis = prob[i], for each row.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311718/add-horizontal-line-to-ggplot-for-specified-interval-of-x-axis) solution, using a "for loop" to plot each segment:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = df)

for(i in 1:15){
   plot <- plot + geom_segment(aes(x = df$inf[i], xend = df$sup[i], y = df$prob[i], yend = df$prob[i]))
}
plot
```

But all i get is a single line in y = 0; i assume because my "prob" has values close to zero. The other problem is that if the for loop goes up to a decent value, an error pops saying:

```
Error: nested evaluation too deep; Infinite recursion options (expressions =)?
```

Is there any way to plot those segments by its x intervals?
Or maybe abandon the idea of intervals and plot some points per interval would be better?

Comment: You're overthinking it. `ggplot(df) + geom_segment(aes(x = inf, xend = sup, y = prob, yend = prob)`

Comment: Never use `$` inside `aes`.

Comment: @Brian 's solution worked just fine, thank you very much